# convert a code from java into python

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, usbserial

Now I am trying to change a program from Java into Python, when I finally fix three problems on my code and I run it. Then shows me this Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial.py", line 4, in <module>
    import serial
  File "/home/pi/serial.py", line , in <module>
    port=serial.Serial(
AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'
```

How can I fix it?

If you need the source code and What were the problems that I had to fix, let me know. Please help me about it.

Comment: Please add relevant part of your code (`serial.py` around line 4)

Comment: Are you trying to import a `serial` module within a module also named `serial`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've most likely named your file serial.py or maybe Serial.py. Rename your file to something else, "TestSerial.py" if you're desperate to keep that name.

Golden Rule of Python: Never give a file the same name as a module you are importing from

Answer (score 1):

I think import serial is wrong.

Did you try:-

from serial import serial

http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simple - **you have given your script file the same name as the library you are importing.**

**Fix:** rename your file to some other name, e.g. serial.py -> serial_test.py
and this should fix the problem.